# Sqlite3 query in objective c

Tags: objective-c, iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, sqlite

```
  -(IBAction)ButtonPressed:(id)sender
    { 
        const char *sql = "SELECT AccessCode FROM UserAccess";
        NSString *sqlns;
        sqlns = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:sql];
        if([Password.text isEqual:sqlns])
        {
            NSLog(@"Correct");
        }
            else {
                NSLog(@"Wrong");
            }

    NSLog(@"%@",sqlns);
    }
```

Noob here , 
At NSLog I am able to print "SELECT AccessCode FROM UserAccess" where as let say the access code is 1234 , which I want .The challenge is to execute the command so that I can retrieve
1234 from the Column AccessCode in the Table UserAccess in the datable UserAcess.sqlite
My Database and table name are same oops .
In the appdelegate I Have : 
///

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after app launch 
    [self createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];    
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

///

```
 - (void)createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded {

        NSLog(@"Creating editable copy of database");

        // First, test for existence.

        BOOL success;

        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

        NSError *error;

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"UserAccess.sqlite"];

        success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];

        if (success) return;

        // The writable database does not exist, so copy the default to the appropriate location.

        NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"UserAccess.sqlite"];

        success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];

        if (!success) {

            NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);

        }

    }
```

///

```
+(sqlite3 *) getNewDBConnection{

    sqlite3 *newDBconnection;

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"UserAccess.sqlite"];

    // Open the database. The database was prepared outside the application.

    if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &newDBconnection) == SQLITE_OK) {

        NSLog(@"Database Successfully Opened :) ");

    } else {

        NSLog(@"Error in opening database :( ");

              }

              return newDBconnection;

              }
```

Please help :(

Comment: You should use an Objective-C string constant `NSString *sqlns = @"SELECT AccessCode FROM UserAccess";` rather than the convoluted method of generating an Objective-C string from a C string that you are using.

Comment: I want the value from the Column 'AccessCode' , in NSLog(@"%@",sqlns);
I should get 1234 instead of : SELECT AccessCode FROM UserAccess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make some sqlite3 calls to execute the select statement and retrieve the column values.

[The sqlite3 quick start](http://www.sqlite.org/quickstart.html) has everything in it you need to know for this particular task.